# Las extendedProps sólo se muestran en la vista de mes en fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Necesito mostrar algunos datos con `extendedProps`, pero cuando trato de mostrarlo con `info.event.extendedProps.description` en `timeGridWeek` o `timeGridDay` no lo hace (pone "undefined"), sólo lo muestra en `dayGridMonth`.

Los eventos los cargo con dos php que me traen correctamente los eventos, ya que se muestran correctamente en el calendar. Ya he probado muchas cosas y no termino de dar con la tecla...

Pego el código que tengo para el calendar:

```
<script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction', 'bootstrap', 'timeGrid', 'rrule' ],
          height: 'parent',
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
          },
          titleFormat: {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'long',
            day: '2-digit'
          },
          defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
          selectable: true,
          editable: true,
          navLinks: true,
          weekNumbers: true,
          nowIndicator: true,
          locale: 'es',
          minTime: '08:00:00',
          maxTime: '22:00:00',
          weekends: false,
          eventOrder : 'color',
          eventSources: [
            'carga_citas.php',
            'carga_sesiones.php'
          ],
          eventClick: function(info) {
            alert(info.event.extendedProps.description);
          }
        });

        calendar.render();
      });
    </script>
```

Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

EDITO para añadir:

Los datos los mando codificados con json_encode, si hago print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 30939
            [title] => David Fernández Fernández
            [start] => 2019-11-26 00:00:00
            [end] => 2019-11-26 01:00:00
            [color] => #A47AE2
            [textColor] => #000000
            [description] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 30963
            [title] => Pedro Fernández Fernández
            [start] => 2019-11-27 00:00:00
            [end] => 2019-11-27 01:00:00
            [color] => #A47AE2
            [textColor] => #000000
            [description] => 3
        )
)
```

Hay cientos, esto es un extracto. Espero que ayude.

Comment: Podrías incluir un extracto de la respuesta para poder replicar el error?

Comment: Hola Paulo. No entiendo a qué te refieres con la respuesta. ¿Te refieres a lo que trae 'carga_citas.php' y 'carga_sesiones.php'?

Comment: Claro.. así podemos ayudarte de mejor forma al poder debuguear

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta con la respuesta, en realidad la idea es que en description vayan más cosas y además poner más propiedades que me ayuden a llevar más información.

Comment: Bueno, ya lo he resuelto. Muchas gracias a Paulo Urbano Rivera por el interés e intentar ayudarme, porque me pusiste sobre la pista.

Resulta que el problema lo tenía en uno de los dos archivos que traían los resultados. Un pequeño error hacía que los últimos resultados, que era sobre los que estaba haciendo las pruebas, no trajesen bien descrito el campo "description".

Ahora ya funciona. Perdón por las molestias.

Comment: Excelente :D.. considera publicar tu solución para colegas que tengas tu mismo problema en un futuro ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente el problema lo tenía en la respuesta de uno de los `evenSources`, precisamente en el que traía los eventos más recientes, que eran los que yo estaba comprobando. Al mirar en el modo mes, los primeros que me aparecían eran de primeros de mes, que los traía el otro archivo, por lo que no daba ningún problema y me hacía pensar que el problema estaba en el tipo de vista. Esto es lo que tenía en ese archivo:

```
<?php
require_once('conexionPDO.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$db=conectar();
$consulta="SELECT citas_prox.id as id, paciente.nombre as title, citas_prox.fecha as start, ADDTIME(citas_prox.fecha,'01:00:00') as end, usuarios.color as color, usuarios.letra_color as textColor FROM citas_prox, paciente, usuarios WHERE citas_prox.paciente=paciente.numero AND citas_prox.usuario=usuarios.id";
$result=$db->prepare($consulta);
$result->execute();

$resultado=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Y esto el archivo correcto:

```
<?php
require_once('conexionPDO.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$db=conectar();
$consulta="SELECT citas_prox.id as id, paciente.nombre as title, citas_prox.fecha as start, ADDTIME(citas_prox.fecha,'01:00:00') as end, usuarios.color as color, usuarios.letra_color as textColor, citas_prox.usuario as description FROM citas_prox, paciente, usuarios WHERE citas_prox.paciente=paciente.numero AND citas_prox.usuario=usuarios.id";
$result=$db->prepare($consulta);
$result->execute();

$resultado=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Esto: **citas_prox.usuario as description** estaba bien puesto en el otro archivo, en este se me había olvidado... Muchas gracias por la pista a  Paulo Urbano Rivera